# How to Separate Strings with Irregular Number of Delimitors and Concanate in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of phone numbers like 01-665-678744, or 02-0512-6789-4567, something like that.  Assume this column is in Column D.  I would like split the number with '-', only but the first part in the column to the left of it: column C, and left the rest to still store in column d.  So After running the code, below would be the effect:

|01 | 665-678744|
|02 |0512-6789-4567|

I feel I should use in array or split, and perhaps UBound, but am not able to create it.
Can anybody help me?
Thank you.

Comment: You can do this with formula, =MID(J30,1,FIND("-",J30)-1) and =MID(J30,FIND("-",J30)+1,LEN(J30)-FIND("-",J30)) acting on cell J30.

Comment: Yes, I understand it can be done by creating a formula.  But I am asking this because I want to automate my monthly job,  Also I think even if I create the formula in VBA, the speed is still slow compared to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub test()
 Dim i As Long, Rng As Range, Cnt As Long
 Dim VV As Variant, V1() As String, Sp() As String

 Set Rng = Range("d1:d5") ' change this as you need but don't use column "A"
 Cnt = Rng.Rows.Count
 ReDim V1(1 To Cnt, 1 To 2)
 VV = Rng.Value

  For i = 1 To Cnt
    Sp = Split(VV(i, 1), "-")
    V1(i, 1) = Sp(0)
    V1(i, 2) = Right(VV(i, 1), Len(VV(i, 1)) - Len(Sp(0)) - 1)
  Next

  Range(Rng, Rng.Offset(, -1)) = V1

End Sub
```

If your range can contain empty cells or any value without "-", you can use this code:

```
Sub telf()
 Dim i As Long, Rng As Range, Cnt As Long
 Dim VV As Variant, V1() As String, Sp() As String

 Set Rng = Range("d1:d10") ' change this as you need but don't use column "A"
 Cnt = Rng.Rows.Count
 ReDim V1(1 To Cnt, 1 To 2)
 VV = Rng.Value
 On Error Resume Next
  For i = 1 To Cnt
    Sp = Split(VV(i, 1), "-")
    If UBound(Sp) = 0 Then
     V1(i, 2) = VV(i, 1)
    Else
     V1(i, 1) = Sp(0)
     V1(i, 2) = Right(VV(i, 1), Len(VV(i, 1)) - Len(Sp(0)) - 1)
    End If
  Next

  Range(Rng, Rng.Offset(, -1)) = V1
 On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, both of them works perfectly.  May I ask what does the last bit of the code do? "Range(Rng, Rng.Offset(, -1)) = V1"  Thanks.

Comment: @lukayl, this line is for get the target range, we can't use `resize` in this case because we need `offset(0,-1)` .

Comment: @lukayl, the target range must have the same size as the array, so we need to resize it.

Comment: I just don't get it why Rng is before the Rng.Offset(0, -1) in the last line.

Comment: @lukayl , `Rng` is the original range = column `D` in our example and `Rng.Offset(, -1)` give us column `C` , then we need to make them one range so we use `Range(Rng, Rng.Offset(, -1))`, because our array `V1` has 2 columns .

Comment: Yes, this bit I got.  I am just now sure why Range(Rng, Rng.Offset(0, -1)), instead of Range(Rng.offset(0, -1), Rng). I mean V1( i , 1) is the first part which should be stored in Rng.Offset(0, -1), right?

Comment: @lukayl, `Range(Rng.offset(0, -1), Rng)` and `Range(Rng, Rng.Offset(, -1))` both are the same, VBA take care about that . I just used to put the original range first :). you can use `Range(Rng.offset(0, -1), Rng)`.

Comment: @lukayl, You are Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to overwrite Column D, you'll want VBA (which you asked for).  You can do this with a formula just as easily (if not a little more so), you'll just need a helper column.

Here's a sub for what you're trying to get:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow&
Dim firstPart$, secondPart$
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(lastRow, 4))

For Each cel In rng
    firstPart = Left(cel.Value, 2)
    secondPart = Mid(cel.Value, 4, Len(cel.Value))
    Debug.Print firstPart & ", " & secondPart
    cel.Offset(0, -1).Value = "'" & firstPart
    cel.Value = secondPart
Next cel

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Acting on J30, you can use a loop for each cell.

```
Sub test()

    Dim strSplitOne() As String

    strSplitOne = Split(Range("J30").Value, "-")

    Range("J30").Offset(0, 1).Value = "'" & strSplitOne(0)

    strSplitOne(0) = ""

    Range("J30").Offset(0, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Join(strSplitOne, "-"), "-", "", 1)


End Sub
```